# I am trying to install MySql on Debian 10 and keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, debian

I keep trying to install either MySql or MariaDb on a fresh installation of Debian 10. Should be a simple process,(sudo  apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client)
 but I keep getting this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.4 (>= 
1:10.4.7+maria~buster) but it is not going to be installed
mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.4 (>= 
1:10.4.7+maria~buster) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is a fresh install. PHP and Apache2 are installed. I have tried several times using first MySql and then when that didn't work, I tried using MariaDb, but still get the same error. Not sure what else to do. I tried googling and the only thing close suggested ensuring that it wasn't installed and even purging any previous installations. I tried that but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with this about 4 hours, I finally figured it out. When installing Debian, I was presented with some options regarding software to install. One of those options was to install Web server software. So, I chose to do so. That was a mistake. First, you don't get all of the needed php modules by selected that option. Secondly, that selection does install some of what is needed for MySql, but not enough to actually work.
So, in the end, for anyone else who has this issue, this is how I fixed it.
First, run the commands:

```
    sudo service mysql stop
    sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
    sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

Then, make sure everything is gone by running

```
   sudo updatedb
   locate mysql
```

You will still see a few things, but make sure that you don't see a my.cnf file. That was the culprit in my case. If you do see it, delete it as well.
Now reinstall MySql and you shouldn't have any issues. If you are also installing phpMyAdmin, you will still need to run one more command to get the needed extensions.

```
    sudo apt install php-imagick php-phpseclib php-php-gettext php7.3-common 
    php7.3-gd php7.3-imap php7.3-json php7.3-curl php7.3-zip php7.3-xml 
    php7.3-mbstring php7.3-bz2 php7.3-intl php7.3-gmp
```